# Why is my loop breaking early?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am writing a function for class that takes an amount of money and tells the user how many coins add up to that amount. I seem to have everything working just fine, except pennies. My loop will sometimes stop short and break before adding the proper amount. It usually will stop 1 penny short, but sometimes it will give me the proper answer (one value I have found that gives the correct answer is .09). I've tried changing the float to a double, and I have the same issue. I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
void change(float total)
{
int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
quarters = 0;
dimes = 0;
nickels = 0;
pennies = 0;

printf("\nTotal value entered: %.2f", total);

while (total >= .25)
{
    quarters += 1;
    total -= .25;
}
while (total >= .10)
{
    dimes += 1;
    total -= .10;
}
while (total >= .05)
{
    nickels += 1;
    total -= .05;
}
while (total >= .01)
{
    pennies += 1;
    total -= .01;
}
printf("\nQuarters: %d \nDimes: %d \nNickels: %d \nPennies: %d\n\n", quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us for which value of `total` is the issue reproduced, please?

Comment: Lots of decimal numbers (including 0.1, 0.05 and 0.01) are not exactly representable in floating point, and the errors add up.

Comment: It may be related to precision of `float`. What you can do is to handle the money in `cents` and not `dollar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost *certainly* caused by the limited precision of floating point numbers.

You'll probably find that you're reaching a point where the remaining value is something like `0.009999942` rather than `0.1` and that's why you're exiting early.

But it can show itself even before you reach pennies, if you end up with something like `0.249999` left, which *should* be a quarter but precision limits may force down to two dimes and four pennies.

As to *solving* it, I'd get the floating point value rounded to an integer as quickly as possible (multiplying it by a hundred beforehand of course), then you don't have to worry about floating point precision.

You can do this with something like:

```
int itotal = total * 100 + 0.2;
```

then using `itotal` for your calculations:

```
while (itotal >= 25) {
    quarters++;
    itotal -= 25;
}
// and so on ...
```

Comment: Unless you are a high-frequency stock trader and need a reliable way to skim a fraction from each transaction...

Comment: To make this visible use `%e`to print (shows me 9.999998e-03 for the remaining value instead of 0.01 with `%f`)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question a while back for one of my labs. Instead of a a while loop for each coin denominations, i had a single do..while with cascaded if statements. In my case the max cost of an item was $1, and I opted to work in ints, but you can format the final output later.

```
int price, remainder, quarters, dime, nickel, pennies;

printf("Enter the price of the item you bought:>");
scanf("%d", &price);

remainder = 100 - price;

do {
    if (remainder >= 25)
    {
        quarters++;
        remainder -= 25;
    }

    else if (remainder >= 10)
    {
        dime++;
        remainder -= 10;
    }

    else if (remainder >= 5)
    {
        nickel ++;
        remainder -=5;
    }
    else if (remainder >= 1)
    {
        pennies ++;
        remainder -=1;
    }
} while (remainder > 0);

printf("\nYour change will be dispensed as:\n Quarters: %d \n Dimes: %d \n Nickel: %d  \n Pennies: %d \n\n", quarters, dime, nickel,pennies);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math is not exact.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This ought to be a comment unless you quote important passages from the link and make constructive suggestions

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: teach a man to fish, get shouted down on the Internet!

Comment: I love the one from Discworld (I think): give a man a fire, he'll be warm for the night, set him on fire, he'll be warm for the rest of his life :-)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math is very complex and subject to many common mis expectations. Try converting your math to using int, and later translate it back.

Answer (score 0):

As you are comparing float which subjected to be full of errors so you can use a roundof function and change the floating point number to integer.

```
int_total = round( total * 100.0  );         //include math.h
```

Now, change the loop as,

```
while (total >= 25)
{
    quarters += 1;
    total -= 25;
}
```